# Can i use Elasticsearch with data that needs authentication to view(ex.Logged in users only)

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I want to implement searching on my website.Users should be able to search for products that they have in their shop.Obviously,the products returned should only be theirs,same if customers search on their website.How can i implement this with Elasticsearch?Obviously,i will have my backend do the query not the front-end,but how will i limit the search results to be only for one user.Is it only possible through filtering with my own code.Does it have something like WHERE from sql?Am i going about it the wrong way?Will it be better if i use the Full text search from PostgreSQL.

I am using GO btw.

Best regards

Update:My usecase as requested:

User is paired with an ID.He is in his dashboard and searches for a product he has in his shop.His requests passes the session token cookie and i get his ID on my server.Then i need to get the products that match his query and only his.

In SQL it would be `SELECT * FROM products WHERE shop_id=ID` for example.Is it possible with Elasticsearch?Is it more trouble than worth instead of implementing full text search on PostgreSQL?

Comment: you can set the user as a field in your source json when indexing and can query by that field. Elasticsearch supports various types of queries as mentioned in documentation https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/search-request-body.html It would help if you put your usecase more clearly, possibly with an example data.

Comment: Hi @pkp9999,Thanks for the suggestion.I updated my OP.I hope it helps a little..

Comment: @AlexTselikas, provided answer, please go through it and let me know if you have further questions, would be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iy can be easily achieved using Elasticsearch and you should define `shop_id` as a keyword field and later on use that in filter context of query to make sure, you search only on the products belong to a particular `shop_id`.

Using `shop_id` in filter context also improves the performance of your search significantly as these are by default cached at Elasticsearch as explained in [the official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context)

> In a filter context, a query clause answers the question “Does this
>   document match this query clause?” The answer is a simple Yes or
>   No — no scores are calculated. Filter context is mostly used for
>   filtering structured data, e.g.
>
> Is the status field set to "published"?

**Frequently used filters will be cached automatically by Elasticsearch, to speed up performance.**

**Sample mapping and query according to your requirement:**

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings" :{
        "properties" : {
            "product" : {
                "type" : "text"
            },
            "shop_id" :{
                "type" : "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Index sample docs for 2 diff shop ids**

```
{
    "product" : "foo",
    "shop_id" : "stackoverflow"
}

{
    "product" : "foo",
    "shop_id" : "opster"
}
```

**Search for `foo` product where shop_id is `stackoverflow`**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "product": "foo"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "shop_id": "stackoverflow"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "productshop",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 0.18232156,
                "_source": {.  --> note only foo belong to `stackoverflow` returned
                    "product": "foo",
                    "shop_id": "stackoverflow"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Hey,thanks for the detailed response!I will try it as soon as i have free time and get back to you

Comment: Just tested and it's exactly what i was looking for, thanks!